# i get this error CS1061: 'Rigidbody2D' does not contain a definition for 'velociy'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

heres full error Im confused at where it occurs or how to fix it `error CS1061: 'Rigidbody2D' does not contain a definition for 'velociy' and no accessible extension method 'velociy' accepting a first argument of type 'Rigidbody2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

here is my code, I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdY-V6k_58k) tutorial. Please Help. Im new to Unity and have literally spent day and night on this game. It worked up until the the most recent edition of code

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpForce;

    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

    public bool grounded;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    private Collider2D myCollider;

    private Animator myAnimator;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        myCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();

        myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        grounded = Physics2D.IsTouchingLayers(myCollider, whatIsGround);

        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            if (grounded)
            {
                myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpForce);

            }
        }

        myAnimator.SetFloat ("Speed", myRigidbody.velociy.x);
        myAnimator.SetBool ("Grounded", grounded);
    }
}
```

Comment: You misspelled `velocity`.  Look at the error message again.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see where I did it lol I thought  maybe it was due to videos age thankyou

Answer (score 1):

It's just a typo, change `velociy` to `velocity` and you're ready to go.